# I need help with determining angles after shifting of axis in Free Body Diagrams

Tags: homework-and-exercises, free-body-diagram, statics, equilibrium

[image: Free body diagram]

I can't figure out by which property of the triangle the angles in shifted axis are also 30 degrees. Vertical angle theorom doesn't work. I drew it again and again. If someone could draw me a diagram, I'd understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They take a symmetry axis about *B*

[image: pic]

So the angle *DBE* is split into two 30° angles.